# read database in spring batch based on reading List<Hashmap<String,String>>

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am having a scenario where i need to read data from an list which contains hashmap.After reading through various forums i am able to understand and even make use of jdbccursor item reader to read database by standard query. But not sure how to retrieve this list of hashmap from previous step to dynamically create query

Below is my current code where i am running a hard coded query , instead i want to receive list of hashmap and create select query and then run it

```
    @StepScope
    private JdbcCursorItemReader<List<HashMap<String, String>>> checkDatExist(@Value("#{jobParameters['tableName']}") String tableName) {


    JdbcCursorItemReader<List<HashMap<String, String>>> getExcelData = new JdbcCursorItemReader<List<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    getExcelData.setDataSource(dataSource);
    getExcelData.setSql("SELECT id from "+tableName);
    getExcelData.setRowMapper(new dbMapper());
    return getExcelData;

}
```

Any thoughts please

Answer (score 0):

You can put this map to ExecutionContext in the previous step and read it in your Reader.

```
@Component
@JobScope
class PreviousStep {

   @Value("#{jobExecution.executionContext}")
   private ExecutionContext executionContext;

   public void someFunction() {
     this.executionContext.put("someVariable", mapYouWantToStore);
   }
}
```

You have to do the same in You Reader class. Just Autowire ExecutionContext as above and then do get on "someVariable".

```
this.executionContext.get("someVariable");
```

This will get you the map you store in previous step.

Comment: thanks , i have tried something similar but still missing something. In my previous writer i have written like